# Blogdown Site not showing my Images after deploying on Netlify

Tags: r, rstudio, netlify, hugo, blogdown

After updating Blogdown package (1.3.2) and with Hugo version 0.79.0, there's a modification on my .html files generated by .Rmd files. The images now have this string: `{{< blogdown/postref >}}` that wasn't present before. See below example.

```
<p><img src="{{< blogdown/postref >}}index.en_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-5-1.png" width="432" style="display: block; margin: auto;" /></p>
```

Then, the site after being deployed on Netlify, doesn't show the images of the .Rmd file.

Here's the link of my Github repo: https://github.com/FranciscoPiccolo/franciscopiccolo.github.io

Link of the webpage: https://franciscopiccolo.netlify.app/post/2019-09-05-residual-analysis-in-econometric-models/

Check site ouput:

```
> blogdown::check_site()
― Running a series of automated checks for your blogdown website project...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
○ A successful check looks like this.
● [TODO] A check that needs your attention looks like this.
| Let's check out your blogdown site!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
― Checking config.toml
| Checking "baseURL" setting for Hugo...
○ Found baseURL = "https://francisco.piccolo.com/"; nothing to do here!
| Checking "ignoreFiles" setting for Hugo...
○ "ignoreFiles" looks good - nothing to do here!
| Checking setting for Hugo's Markdown renderer...
○ All set! Found the "unsafe" setting for goldmark.
― Check complete: config.toml

― Checking .gitignore
| Checking for items to remove...
○ Nothing to see here - found no items to remove.
| Checking for items to change...
● [TODO] Change items in .gitignore: resources -> /resources
| Checking for items you can safely ignore...
○ Found! You have safely ignored: .DS_Store, Thumbs.db
| Checking for items to ignore if you build the site on Netlify...
● [TODO] When Netlify builds your site, you can safely add to .gitignore: /public/, /resources/
| Checking for files required by blogdown but not committed...
○ Great! Did not find such files.
― Check complete: .gitignore

― Checking Hugo
| Checking Hugo version...
○ Found Hugo. You are using Hugo 0.79.0.
| Checking .Rprofile for Hugo version used by blogdown...
| Hugo version not set in .Rprofile.
● [TODO] Set options(blogdown.hugo.version = "0.79.0") in .Rprofile and restart R.
― Check complete: Hugo

― Checking netlify.toml...
○ Found HUGO_VERSION = 0.79.0 in [build] context of netlify.toml.
| Checking that Netlify & local Hugo versions match...
○ It's a match! Blogdown and Netlify are using the same Hugo version (0.79.0).
| Checking that Netlify & local Hugo publish directories match...
○ Good to go - blogdown and Netlify are using the same publish directory: public
― Check complete: netlify.toml

― Checking content files
| Checking for validity of YAML metadata in posts...
○ All YAML metadata appears to be syntactically valid.
| Checking for previewed content that will not be published...
○ Found 0 files with future publish dates.
● [TODO] Found 2 files marked as drafts. To un-draft, run the command:

  blogdown::edit_draft(c(
  "content/privacy.md",
  "content/terms.md"
  ))

  and change a file's YAML from 'draft: true' to 'draft: false' or delete it
| Checking your R Markdown content...
○ All R Markdown files have been knitted.
○ All R Markdown output files are up to date with their source files.
| Checking for .html/.md files to clean up...
○ Found 0 duplicate .html output files.
○ Found 0 incompatible .html files to clean up.
| Checking for the unnecessary 'content/' directory in theme...
○ Great! Your theme does not contain the content/ directory.
― Check complete: Content
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you modified the file `postref.html` in [this commit](https://github.com/FranciscoPiccolo/franciscopiccolo.github.io/commit/f615888881000d97500ffc45c1127839f2f7754c#diff-fb7c667006c25d5da462f9e327e9fa13a1646c4407579d6980136cb516997e0a) and added an EOL to it. This file must not have an EOL. To fix the problem, run this in your R console:

```r
blogdown:::create_shortcode('postref.html', 'blogdown/postref', force = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Yihui, I've ran this code and now I'll check if it worked.

Comment: After run this code, I just have to commit on master branch or do I need to run ```blogdown::server_site()``` again? The page on Netlify is not showing the images.

Comment: Just commit it. The commit https://github.com/FranciscoPiccolo/franciscopiccolo.github.io/commit/6310ecbae2859ffd47f589335af1697b5e86bd94 has fixed the problem mentioned in your post above. You still don't see the images because your domain `francisco.piccolo.com` is not properly configured: https://github.com/FranciscoPiccolo/franciscopiccolo.github.io/blob/6310ecbae2859ffd47f589335af1697b5e86bd94/config.toml#L14 If you don't know how to configure it, you need to use `https://franciscopiccolo.netlify.app/` or `/` as the `baseURL`.

Comment: Ok, so I'll close this issue as the problem with the image not appearing is being caused by other misconfiguration. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to note, after adjusting the domain the images now appear :)

Comment: I did this but then I also had to set `[context.deploy-preview.environment]
  HUGO_BLOGDOWN_POST_RELREF = "true"` on my netlify.toml  file following the advice on this post https://answers.netlify.com/t/can-i-have-a-different-set-of-environment-variables-for-deploy-previews/15235/4. I needed that to display the images of new posts on the preview created via a PR (without merging it)